# I can't install a specific udhcpd version

Tags: package-management

`sudo apt-cache policy udhcpd` :

```
udhcpd:
Installed: 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1
Candidate: 1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1
```

sudo apt-get install udhcpd=1:1.22.0-9+dev8u1

```
E: Version '1:1.22.0-9+dev8u1' for 'udhcpd' was not found
```

I've also tried various ways to write it like:

```
1.22.0-9+dev8u1
1.22.0
1.22.0-9
```

any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command should be:

```
sudo apt-get install udhcpd=1:1.22.0-9+deb8u1
```

The mistake is the `v` on udhcpd=1:1.22.0-9+de**v**8u1

Comment: Why do the v and b have to be so close together haha Thanks for the catch.